# What is the most correct way to change endianess of floating point numbers

Tags: c++, endianness

Having read this: http://commandcenter.blogspot.fi/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html

The method in the article is this:

Read from big endian:

```
int i = (data[3]<<0) | (data[2]<<8) | (data[1]<<16) | (data[0]<<24);
```

Read from little endian:

```
int i = (data[0]<<0) | (data[1]<<8) | (data[2]<<16) | (data[3]<<24);
```

Is there any way to convert this ideology to floating point numbers?

So is there any way to avoid the `if(swap_needed) swap(data);`

One thought I had was to read the sign bit, mantissa and exponent individually from the data calculate the floating point value based on them.

Comment: If you are reading and writing the files, you can pick one of the two endiannesses and always read/write in that layout regardless of the machine type.

Comment: To answer your question regarding floating point numbers: No. Floating point numbers doesn't have "endianness" in the same way integer numbers have.

Comment: @NeilKirk what's the way to read/write in the specific layout regardless of the machine type?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg They still (can have) different in memory representation based on the endianess of the host, the IEEE format doesn't dictate that part.

Comment: Assume picking little-endian (the most common). On LE machine, write out. On BE machine, convert underlying bytes to LE order and then write out. On LE machine, just read back. On BE machine, read and convert to BE order.

Comment: That's my point, I want to write code that works on every machine, without actually knowing what the byte order is, for the machine. Sure I must know in what format it's in the file.

Comment: I don't really understand the question: either your floats are stored in binary format in a file, and you need to know the endianness of the file to read the floats correctly, or the floats are stored as text, and you need to parse them. Or do you mean: is there a way to detect in a (binary stored) float bit pattern if it's big or little endian?

Comment: On LE Machine .... starts out wrong, I don't want to bind my code to any certain endianess, sure the format in the file is LE or BE and I need to read accordingly. But my code should care what the format of the machine is I am reading on. Like the code I posted in the example, the same code correctly reads LE and BE numbers on any machine, LE, BE, PDP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sebastian Redl's answer is correct if you stay with simple non-Intel IEEE-754 float or double, but it will fail with Intel's special representation of double and long double, and all other special ideas for their long double formats. Only very few architectures use the standard IEEE-754 floating point formats.
Even the easiest mips, which can use BE/LE at will, has a special MIPS64 16 byte long double format.

So there's no correct and easy way to do a fast byteswap for floats. However I wrote code to read floats from various architectures into the current architecture, which is a herculean task. https://github.com/parrot/parrot/blob/native_pbc2/src/packfile/pf_items.c#L553
Note: The intel speciality is the extra normalization bit (the highest bit 63 of the mantissa) marked with i in https://github.com/parrot/parrot/blob/native_pbc2/src/packfile/pf_items.c#L605

I.e. I convert between those, BE and LE:

- Floattype 0 = IEEE-754 8 byte double (binary64)
- Floattype 1 = Intel 80-bit long double stored in 12 byte (i386) or aligned to 16 byte (x86_64/ia64)
- Floattype 2 = IEEE-754 128 bit quad precision stored in 16 byte, Sparc64 quad-float or __float128, gcc since 4.3 (binary128)
- Floattype 3 = IEEE-754 4 byte float (binary32)
- Floattype 4 = PowerPC 16 byte double-double (-mlong-double-128)

not yet:

- Floattype 5 = IEEE-754 2 byte half-precision float (binary16)
- Floattype 6 = MIPS64 16 byte long double
- Floattype 7 = AIX 16 byte long double
- CRAY and more crazyness

Since there was no big need, I never made a proper library for this float-conversion code.
Btw. I use much faster native byteswap functions, see https://github.com/parrot/parrot/blob/native_pbc2/include/parrot/bswap.h

Usually you print with max. precision to a string and read this string. There you only have the problem to find out your max. precision.

Comment: I looked at how the code works, it looks quite like what i did, extracting the various pieces of the floating point numbers and re-calculating the number from them. What I don't understand is why I got downvoted, do you spot something awfully wrong with my basic idea of conversion? I do realize that it doesn't handle all formats and all cases, but the basic idea IS there.

Comment: Do you mean that the Intel representation for `double` is not IEEE-754? Of course the 80-bit `long double` is Intel-specific, but what about the 64-bit `double`? Your post seems to imply that even `double` is not IEEE-754 in Intel (and even raises doubts about `float`, just read your first line).

Answer (score 1):

You just grab the underlying bytes and work with that.

```
unsigned char underlying[sizeof(float)];

// Writing
std::memcpy(underlying, &my_float, sizeof(float));
if (platform_endian != target_endian)
  std::reverse(std::begin(underlying), std::end(underlying));
write(underlying, sizeof(float));

// Reading
read(underlying, sizeof(float));
if (platform_endian != target_endian)
  std::reverse(std::begin(underlying), std::end(underlying));
std::memcpy(&my_float, underlying, sizeof(float));
```

You can of course optimize the reverse to something super-special if you feel so inclined.

Answer (score 0):

You will usually see people cast to a unsigned 64 bit integer, and then call the classic BSD functions to convert to/from network byte order.  I once worked on a project where I got `double`s over the network from a Java machine, so I knew they were sent big-endian, and read them on an Intel machine in C++.  I simply read the data as a `char[8]`, called `std::reverse`, and cast the result to a `double`:

```
double read_double()
{
    char buffer[8];
    // read from network into buffer;
    std::reverse(std::begin(buffer), std::end(buffer), std::begin(buffer));
    return *static_cast<double*>(static_cast<void*>(buffer));
}
```

Today I would do things differently.  For one, the bitshifting code you posted isn't that hard to follow.  For another, I agree with @NeilKirk and the article you linked to:  the code to read/write from a particular endianness is identical regardless of the actual endianness on the machine, so just write code that will read big-endian/little-endian data, using the code from the article you linked to (just cast it to a `double` after you've read and manipulated the bytes as a 64 bit unsigned integer type).